# Strange sorting requirement with XSLT

Tags: xslt, sorting

I have a strange requirement.

I have a variable in xslt containing the months, with their id (1-12)

The issue is I need to display them all, but starting with a month other than January(1).

Currently I have the following

```
<xsl:variable name="months">
    <Months>
        <Month ID="1">JAN</Month>
        <Month ID="2">FEB</Month>
        <Month ID="3">MAR</Month>
        <Month ID="4">APR</Month>
        <Month ID="5">MAY</Month>
        <Month ID="6">JUN</Month>
        <Month ID="7">JUL</Month>
        <Month ID="8">AUG</Month>
        <Month ID="9">SEP</Month>
        <Month ID="10">OCT</Month>
        <Month ID="11">NOV</Month>
        <Month ID="12">DEC</Month>
    </Months>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then I iterate with this so that I can start at a given month

```
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($months)//Month[@ID >= $startAtMonth]">
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="@ID"/>
    <th>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </th>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($months)//Month[not(@ID >= $startAtMonth)]">
    <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="@ID"/>
    <th>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </th>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it requires two for-each statements, and this for-each will be needed in a few places.  Is there a more concise way to write this so it is one loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a modulo operation?

```
<xsl:sort data-type="number" select="(number(@ID)+12-$startAtMonth) mod 12"/>
```

Comment: Nice, I was trying to come up with something similar and just couldn't...Mondays.